# MVC Project does not accept controller name (MemberController)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-controller

My MVC in my project "MemberController" will not accept the name.

What could be the problem.

[image]

Comment: May be it because.you've created a new namespace, but the parent namespace contained a class with the same name.

Comment: The error suggests you already have another `public class MemberController : Controller` defined in your namespace

Comment: Within the project "MemberController" does not pass the word.

Comment: @OğuzhanSari, didn't get you.

Comment: Check all your controllers, You already have a controller with Namespace **MemberController**, and you are trying to create one more.

Comment: You say there is the same.
But nowhere do I see in.
How can I find where he is.

Comment: Try `Entire Solution` option when searching `MemberController`. The results will show up at `Find Results` section in VS window, click the result to see which CS file caused naming conflict.