# Naming a controller "MemberController" causes "Unhandled exception rendering component"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

This guy had a similar issue in MVC, whereas i'm using Blazor WASM: [MVC Project does not accept controller name (MemberController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803044/mvc-project-does-not-accept-controller-name-membercontroller)

Problem: When naming an api controller "MemberController" it causes an "unhandled exception rendering component... etc error":[image]

Is there official documentation stating that we are NOT allowed to create a controller called "MemberController"?

If you want to reproduce for yourself just create a Blazor WASM project and change the WeatherForecastController to MemberController as well as the route to it in the client.

Comment: There is no 0xEF at the start of the JSON file?

Comment: No repro. _____

Comment: Not sure why you added that screenshot, because the exception in it has nothing to do with MemberController